# Selecting multiple path elements in a d3 map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a world map with separate countries as path elements. Each country belongs to a cluster, which is an object containing country names. The names correspond to those in geojson properties of individual features. When clicking on a country, I'd like to change style of entire cluster that the country belongs to.

I can highlight the clicked node, since it's passed in event handler like this:

```
    svg.selectAll("path").data(json.features).enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        var value = d.properties.value;
        var size = d.properties.size;
        if (value) {
            var hsv = hsvToRgb((value / moreThanOne) *0.66, 1, 0.1 + (size / maxSize) * 0.9);
            if (size == 1)  return "#000000";
            else return "rgba(" + Math.floor(hsv[0]) + "," + Math.floor(hsv[1]) + "," + Math.floor(hsv[2]) + ",255)";
        } else return "#999999";
    }).on("click", function(d) {
        var name = d.properties.name;
        var value = d.properties.value;
        hilite(value, this);
    })
```

here is the highlight function:

```
function hilite(cluster, node) { //highlights the single clicked node
d3.select(node).style("stroke", "#ff0000");
//clustermap is the object holding the clusters data
Object.keys(clusterMap[cluster]).forEach(function(key) {
    svg.selectAll("svg").data().each(function(d) {
        if (d.properties.name.toLowerCase() == key.replace(".gif", "").toLowerCase()) {
            //if it matches, style ... but how?
            console.log(d.properties.name.toLowerCase() + " " + key.replace(".gif", "").toLowerCase());
        }
    });
});
```

}

How do I select all the nodes by names and apply styling to them? I'm new to d3, so I guess there must be a simple way to do this, but I cant' figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` to do this, assuming that `cluster` and `d.properties.name` are to be compared:

```
d3.selectAll("path").filter(function(d) {
  return d.properties.name == cluster;
}).style("stroke", "#f00");
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try that, but I have to modify it, since "cluster" is just an id in a clusterMap, which then contains objects with country names, for instance:
1:
   Tanzania: Tanzania
   Australia: Australia
2: 
   country name : country name
etc.
so that function would have to return on multiple selections ...  that's my problem :)

Comment: So where do you get the cluster name for the selected country from?

Comment: yes ... when I first parse the geojson, I append a property ("value") with the cluster name (number), then I get it from the object with "var value = d.properties.value" before calling the hilite finction. 
I modified the code as per your suggestion with an added loop which goes through countries in passed cluster, but it's not doing anything on the styling front. maybe see the code online? : http://virostatiq.com/data/flags/

Comment: So `.value` contains the cluster number and is the same for countries in the same cluster? Then you should be able to just compare that to `cluster` for the filtering.